# How can I compare a date in C# to "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")

Tags: c#

I am trying the following:

```
if (e.CreatedDate == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
```

But this gives me an error saying I cannot compare a date to a string. How can I make it so I check the CreatedDate is equal to the "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" which is I guess the default?

Comment: StackOverflow, Please take out anonymous down voting. Please let the users who vote down to enter a reason for doing so. Not everyone is an expert. I also had to do a date comparison like Melina's case. @Praveen's answer helped me.

Comment: @user007 you should discuss this on the stackoverflow meta site

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.MinValue`, which has exactly the same value:

```
if (e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 17):

To check if it equals the default, you can use the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
if (e.CreatedDate == default(DateTime))
```

Answer (score 11):

"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" this is a `string` datatype. so convert it to `DateTime`.

```
if (e.CreatedDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
{
    //--- To Dos
}
```

But .NET Framework  provide a default way to check this using

`if (e.CreatedDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))`

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

use DateTime.MinValue

```
if (e.CreatedDate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume e.CreateDate is of type DateTime.

Try it like:

```
if (e.CreatedDate == DateTime.Parse("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
```

If your aiming to compare if it's equal to the minimum date then just compare it to DateTime.MinValue. The above example is more generic.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the default value with `DateTime.MinValue`:

```
if (e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use DateTime.Compare(DateTime, DateTime) function, which returns an integer.
Eg.

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.MinValue, e.CreatedDate) == 0){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This condition doesn't work with Lambdas: `(e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue)`. For example,

```
dbset.Select(e => new 
{ 
    Date = e.CreatedDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.UtcNow : e.CreatedDate 
});
```

So, I had to use the `default` keyword:

```
dbset.Select(e => new 
{ 
    Date = e.CreatedDate == default(DateTime) ? DateTime.UtcNow : e.CreatedDate 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need a string compare ,so you can do it like this

```
e.CreatedDate.ToString(FORMAT)=="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dates have different kind then comparison may not work. To ensure kind matching:

```
if(e.CreatedDate.ToUniversalTime() == default(DateTime).ToUniversalTime())
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to put "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" into a date format to compare it in your if.

```
if(e.CreatedDate == ((Date)"1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"))
```

Comment: -1: There is no type called `Date`, and even if you used the correct `DateTime` you can't directly cast it from a `string`